# devExtreme dx-check-box / ¿Porque se lanza unicamente el primer evento de un grupo de checkboxs?

Tags: devexpress

HTML

```
<dxi-item itemType="group" [visible]="true" [caption]="'Fase contable gastos presupuestarios corriente' | translate" [colCount]="1"  cssClass="group_caption_small group_caption_design_1">
  <dxi-item itemType="simple">
    <div *dxTemplate>
      <div class="w-full mb-2">
        <dx-check-box [disabled]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[0].bDisabled" iconSize="22"  hint="Hint" (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableRC($event, aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[0])" [value]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[0].bSeleccionado" text="{{aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[0].label}}"></dx-check-box>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full mb-2">
        <dx-check-box [disabled]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[1].bDisabled" iconSize="22"  hint="Hint" (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedFchNomFaseContablePA($event, aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[1])" [value]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[1].bSeleccionado" text="{{aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[1].label}}"></dx-check-box>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full mb-2">
        <dx-check-box [disabled]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[2].bDisabled" iconSize="22"  hint="Hint" (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableADO($event, aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[2])" [value]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[2].bSeleccionado" text="{{aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[2].label}}"></dx-check-box>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full mb-2">
        <dx-check-box [disabled]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[3].bDisabled" iconSize="22"  hint="Hint" (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableP($event, aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[3])" [value]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[3].bSeleccionado" text="{{aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[3].label}}"></dx-check-box>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full">
        <dx-check-box [disabled]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[4].bDisabled" iconSize="22"  hint="Hint" (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableR($event, aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[4])" [value]="aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[4].bSeleccionado" text="{{aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC[4].label}}"></dx-check-box>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dxi-item>
</dxi-item>
```

TS

```
export const aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC = [
  new cEnumValues('RC - Retención de crédito', 0, eFchNomFaseContableGastosPC.RC, false, false),
  new cEnumValues('PA - Operación pendiente de aplicar a presupuesto', 1, eFchNomFaseContableGastosPC.PA, false, false),
  new cEnumValues('ADO - Reconocimiento de la obligación', 2, eFchNomFaseContableGastosPC.ADO, false, false),
  new cEnumValues('P - Ordenación del pago', 3, eFchNomFaseContableGastosPC.P, false, false),
  new cEnumValues('R - Realización del pago', 4, eFchNomFaseContableGastosPC.R, false, false),
];
```

```
  onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableRC(e, oData: cEnumValues) {
    console.log(e, oData)
  }

  onValueChangedFchNomFaseContablePA(e, oData: cEnumValues) {
    console.log(e, oData)
  }

  onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableADO(e, oData: cEnumValues) {
    console.log(e, oData)
  }

  onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableP(e, oData: cEnumValues) {
    console.log(e, oData)
  }

  onValueChangedFchNomFaseContableR(e, oData: cEnumValues) {
    console.log(e, oData)
  }
```

Que alguien me explique porque se reconoce unicamente el primer checkbox en el onValueChanged e ignora completamente los otros.

2. OPCIÓN 2 -- PRUEBA: (SOLO RECONOCE EL PRIMER CHECK EN EL EVENTO)

```
<dxi-item itemType="group" [visible]="true" [caption]="'Fase contable gastos presupuestarios corriente' | translate" [colCount]="1"  cssClass="group_caption_small group_caption_design_1">
  <dxi-item itemType="simple">
    <div *dxTemplate>

      <ng-container *ngFor="let oDato of aFchNomFaseContableGastosPC; index as i; first as isFirst; last as isLast">
        <div class="w-full" 
          [ngClass]="{
            'mb-2': !isLast,
          }"
        >
          <dx-check-box [disabled]="oDato.bDisabled" iconSize="22"  hint="Hint" (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedFchNomFaseContable($event, oDato)" [value]="oDato.bSeleccionado" text="{{oDato.label}}"></dx-check-box>
        </div>
      </ng-container>

    </div>
  </dxi-item>
</dxi-item>
```

TS

```
  onValueChangedFchNomFaseContable(e, oData: cEnumValues) {

    console.log(e)
  }
```